# sed: using search pattern in output

Tags: sed

I'd like to use the search pattern in the output part of a sed command.  For instance, given the following sed command:

```
sed '/HOSTNAME=/cHOSTNAME=fred' /etc/sysconfig/network
```

I'd like to replace the second instance of "HOSTNAME=" with some escape sequence that references the search term.  Something like this:

```
# this doesn't actually work
sed '/HOSTNAME=/c\?=fred' /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Does anywone know if there's a way to do this or do I have to repeat the search term in the answer.

I know I can do something like this:

```
sed 's/\(HOSTNAME=\)/\1fred/' /etc/sysconfig/network
```

But this is subtly different from what I want -- for instance #HOSTNAME=zug will turn into #HOSTNAME=fred, but I don't want the leading "#".  The first sed example takes care of cases like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these:

```
sed 's/.*\(HOSTNAME=\)/\1fred/' /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Or

```
sed 's/.*\(HOSTNAME=\).*/\1fred/' /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Comment: While the second form does indeed do what I want -- I'm still hoping to find a way to repeat the pattern space in the output -- hopefully using the 'c' command instead of the 's' command as shown in the question.

However, if there is no other answer, then this will be the accepted answer.

Comment: You can move the match from the `s` command to the address, but that's unnecessary in this simple case. Here is what it would look like: `sed '/.*\(HOSTNAME=\).*/ s//\1fred/' /etc/sysconfig/network` The `c\ `, `a\ ` and `i\ ` only work with literal text, they do not do any *substitutions* - that's what the `s///` command is for.